# Ionic Parse JSON Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, json, ionic-framework

I've been working with Ionic lately for a project and I am trying to pull data from an API that gives the results in a JSON object. The object looks something like this:

```
{"status":{"error":"none","code":200,"description":"none","message":"success"},"people":[{"peopleID":"52735","peopleName":"John","streetAddress":"7700 Kennedy Rd","city":"Blacklick","state":"OH","postalCode":"43004","distance":"0.75"},
{"peopleID":"555555","peopleName":"Bill","streetAddress":"7700 Kennedy Rd","city":"Blacklick","state":"OH","postalCode":"43004","distance":"0.75"},
{"peopleID":"52735","peopleName":"John","streetAddress":"7700 Kennedy Rd","city":"Blacklick","state":"OH","postalCode":"43004","distance":"0.75"}]}
```

In my `controller.js` file I have created a controller for a pull to refresh.

```
.controller('PullToRefresh', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http){
    var url = "url defined here";
    $scope.items = [1,2,3];
    $scope.doRefresh = function(){
      console.log('doing refresh');
      console.log(url);
      $http.jsonp(url)
        .success(function(newItems){
          console.log('success');
          $scope.items = newItems;
        })
        .error(function(){
          console.log('error');
        })
        .finally(function(){
          console.log("done");
          $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
        });
    };
  }]);
```

The controller hits the URL just fine, but when the call complete it will error and never hit .success, I receive `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` At this point I am afraid I am still too new to figure this out, I have not had issues with the JSON object before.

Comment: [JSON-P](http://json-p.org/) is "JSON + Padding." If the response from the server is only JSON, lacking the padding, it won't be understood by `$http.jsonp()`. Check any documentation related to the `url` for support for the format.

Comment: Is there a way I can parse the data without JSONP?

Comment: I got it figured out, I wasn't using the correct syntax when the data was being pulled in.